# Can we use Windows UI Library in Xamarin UWP (windows mobile app)

Tags: windows, xamarin, mobile, uwp

Can we use Windows UI Library in Xamarin UWP (windows mobile app).
As I go through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/.

The Windows UI Library (WinUI) is a native user experience (UX) framework for both Windows Desktop and UWP applications.

what is the difference between xamarin UWP and UWP application?

Comment: On Windows, `Xamarin.Forms` runs on top of UWP (or WPF) : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/supported-platforms?tabs=windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we use Windows UI Library in Xamarin UWP (windows mobile app)

You could use Windows UI in Xamarin UWP, but it could not  be written in the Xamarin Forms project, it could only used in to UWP client project. However, Xamarin UWP UI interface was rendered by Xamarin Forms. So it does not make sense that use Windows UI in Xamarin UWP.

For your scenario we suggest use [WinUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/#windows-ui-2x-library) in pure UWP project.